# I moved /etc into /home in Linux Mint, how do I make the system usable again?

Tags: etc, system-recovery

I was making a spare Mint live USB via Unetbootin and when I was looking for my iso file, I misclicked and moved `/etc` into my `/home` directory, which pretty much immediately rendered my system useless. How can I make this partition bootable again?

I tried grabbing the file from a live USB, but permission was denied. I then tried going into Windows and grabbed an ext4 driver that was read only and copied it into that partition, the booted into a live USB and tried to copy the folder into the root directory of my Linux partition, but access was still denied.

How can I revive this system? Is the only way to copy my home directory and reinstall Mint? This is on a Toshiba C55DT-A5106, 12GB RAM, AMD A6 APU, 750 GB HD with 100GB for Mint, the rest to Windows and assorted recovery/swap partitions. The OS in question is Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon 64 bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to boot into a linux live USB (preferably mint or ubuntu), make sure your linux HDD partion is mounted read/write, and use the linux `mv` command to move the directory to the proper location.

This is how I would approach:

1. Boot your system on a Linux Live USB.
2. Use the file manager on the Linux live system to find the Linux
   Mint partition on the hard drive with your /home directory on it.
3. Open a command terminal on the Linux live system. (ie "drop to the
   shell", heh)
4. Type the command `mount`, which will show you a list of disks and
       the directories they're mounted on in the live linux system, for example:

   ```
   ...
   /dev/sda3 on /media/aaa (ro)
   /dev/sda4 on /mnt/a3d2fe6 (ro)
   ...
   ```
5. Find out which directory (the path after "on" in the above output) is your linux mint partition.  You need to look at only the lines which begin with "/dev/".  For each directory, execute

   ```
   ls <dir>/home
   ```

   replacing `<dir>` with the directory name. Do not check "/", that's the root directory of the live usb system.
6. When you find out which mounted directory contains your home directory, issue these commands, replacing "/yourdirectory" with the directory that you've identified in the `mount` command output:

   ```
   sudo mount -o remount,rw  /yourdirectory
   cd /yourdirectory
   sudo mv home/etc etc
   ```